# Scan column only for filtered rows

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible with BigQuery to scan a column only for those rows where some condition is true?

Please consider:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = 'text1'
```

Imagine half of the rows having `col1` equal `text1` and the other half having `text2`.

With the query above, BigQuery will scan both `col1` and `col2` for the entire table and then filter rows out by the `where` clause.

Is there a way to read `col2` after the rows has been filtered?

Comment: what the reason behind this? why you think you need this? because of cost? if so - this will not change cost as anyway whole col2 is scanned - no matter what!

Comment: unless you can partition and optionally cluster your table by col1

Comment: Well, that answers my question. Yes, I am worried about costs. I feel like it wasteful to scan col2 when in my real application it is only relevant for 10% of rows. And in my application col2 consists of repeated records, so there is a lot of data to scan

Comment: consider clustering if applicable to your data

Comment: The tables are exported to BigQuery automatically from Firebase Analytics. I am not sure if clustering is applicable.  
In my application col2 consists of repeated records, so is it correct every record will be scanned when col2 is referenced and I can do nothing to limit data processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the answers in your comments: Take the tables that have been automatically imported into BigQuery, and then optimize then for further querying.

For example, once the tables have been created, do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `mydataset.mytable`
PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp_column)
CLUSTER BY col1
AS
SELECT *
FROM `original.table`
```

If `col1` happens to be a nested column, then you could do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `mydataset.mytable`
PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp_column)
CLUSTER BY col1_u
AS
SELECT *, col1_u
FROM `original.table`, UNNEST(col1) col1_u
```

If the daily data is not enough to make clustering worthwhile, consider partitioning by year:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `mydataset.mytable`
PARTITION BY ts_year
CLUSTER BY col1_u
AS
SELECT *, col1_u, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts_column, YEAR) ts_year
FROM `original.table`, UNNEST(col1) col1_u
```

Comment: Thanks. I have `event_date` (STRING, "20190815") and `event_timestamp` (INT64, 1565843367102067) in my table. Do you happen to know if I can do PARTITION BY DATE with this?

Comment: create a new column with an actual date `DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1565843367102067))`, and partition by it